# Are people from Shandia originally from Sky Island?

Tags: one-piece

I've just rewatched the Skypiea arc, and I realised that 400 years ago, before Jaya Island is blown up by Knocked-Up Stream, people from Shandia have wings.

People living in Sky Island also have wings, or it's more like people with wings are from Sky Island.
Like people in Skypiea, Enel's crew from Birka.

> Urouge also has wings and he's also from an unnamed Sky Island. As we can see, he talks to Kaido before he jumps from Sky Island.

Then, why do people in Shandia also have wings, even before they blew up? Are they originally from another Sky Island?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Shandia were once called the Shandorians. They lived on the moon along with the fellow moon races, the Birkans and Skypieans. The three races had also built a robotic race called the automata. However, when resources on the moon wore out, the three races had to leave the automata behind as they headed for Earth.
while the Birkans and Skypieans settled in the Sky Islands, the Shandorians made it as far as the Blue Sea. They settled on the island of Jaya. They used to be one of the more powerful societies on the Grand Line, but their city of Shandora was invaded during the Void Century by the Twenty Kingdoms. Their kingdom fell and only a small tribe was left.

Though the Shandorians disappeared, they left their descendants a legacy, including the ruins of the golden city of Shandora and the Shandorian Golden Belfry Bell. This was also one of two poneglyphs, containing the details of Poseidon which they had guarded with their lives for generations.

They are related. Plus you can see on the moon tablet that the also had wings from the start since they all are moon races.

Comment: I never heard they're from the moon, can you give me source? is that from anime or manga?

Comment: I believe you find that out at the same time you find out what happens to Enel if I recall correctly.

Comment: I'm only watch until eps. 197 now, it's when Luffy's crew fall from Sky Island, and landed on Marine Base. I know Enel left to the moon, but I think I miss something, or maybe it's explained in next episodes after episode 197?

Comment: It is from "Enels Great Space Operations" which is only a few covers. Most of the information (such as the three races) is from looking closely at ancient paintings on the walls.  Some of these details are speculations but do seem to be Oda's intentions.

Comment: @JTR, no it never occurs in the anime.  All of the images are on the wiki.  As it is in the manga, it is canon while (for instance) the landing in the marine base is not.

Comment: @kaine oh.. okay, thank for your informations everyone!

Comment: It might be a good idea to incorporate links to the info in theanswer, but if they don't, here it is: http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Enel's_Great_Space_Operations